# What does "it's all in ghost in the wires" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I'm watching this video
https://youtu.be/aUqes9QdLQ4?t=492
on youtube. At 8:12, the guest says "it's all in ghost in the wires". I tried looking up *ghost* and *wire* in the dictionary but with no luck. Can someone kindly explain what does it mean? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below the video there is some text.  It begins, “Kevin Mitnick visits Google's NYC office to discuss his book *Ghost in the Wires: My Adventures as the World's Most Wanted Hacker* …”

So when he says “It's all in *Ghost in the Wires*,” he means “I told this story in my book.”

The title describes someone doing sneaky things on the Internet and/or telephone lines.

Comment: And *Ghost in the Wires* is referencing the phrase "Ghost in the machine", for which see wikipedia.